# How to call a script from udev rule as non-root user?

Tags: linux, udev

I have a rule in udev, which backups my files when my usb hdd is plugged.
But I have a problem, all the copied files are accessible only for the root user and I cannot see or use it.

How can I call the copy script from udev an copy the files without root privileges?

Comment: A systemd service I suppose. `man systemd.device` for details.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution/workaround, in called script I added the following command before rsync call. Seems to work good.

```
su - <UserName> -c "rsync -hvrstc /copy/from /copy/to"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Bot Sorry but I found the solution with try and error so I am not sure if it is correct or wrong, but seems to work. So I cannot do something better for you.
PS. I know he is a bot.